Since mathematicians are physical beings, does this mean that mathematics ultimately reduces to physics?
Mathematical reasoning is always performed by an agent capable of such reasoning, whether human or artificial. In the case of a human, this reasoning is carried out by the brain. Each brain state represents a step in the reasoning process, with neurons firing and neural pathways activating as the reasoning unfolds. Occasionally, the thinker may need to jot down partial results on a physical medium like paper, a notebook, or a tablet. In every instance, the information is stored physically. For example, when the mathematician reads their notes, they engage their sense of vision, a physical process involving light (electromagnetic waves), eyes, the visual cortex, neurons, and other biological mechanisms. The brain then continues its reasoning based on the visual input. In essence, every instance of mathematical reasoning in the universe corresponds to physical states evolving over time according to the laws of physics. Even an automated theorem prover, while non-biological, operates as software running on hardware, which is also governed by physical laws.
Whether the reasoning is performed by a biological or artificial agent, or a combination of both, it remains a sequence of physical events unfolding over time.
This raises a significant question: does this imply that mathematics itself reduces to physics? After all, no mathematical conclusion can be reached unless a physical agent, following the constraints of the physical world, is capable of reaching it. Physical agents can only derive mathematical conclusions that are allowed by the laws of physics. The only conceivable exception to this would be the involvement of a supernatural agent—one capable of reasoning beyond the limitations imposed by physical laws. A "supernatural mind" could, in theory, transcend these constraints and reach conclusions that physical agents cannot.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Mathematicians do not causally interact with any Platonic realm. Some may think about "the circle" as if it is an abstract Platonic object, but all they know about circles comes to them from patterns of neural activity; mental images of circles, words and symbols in their brain that mention circles. And in turn, those patterns were not caused by any abstract Platonic objects either.
The Platonic realm was not in the causal loop; its presence or absence did not in any way help the mathematicians come to their conclusions. So how could the mathematicians be speaking about it?
But we do see what we might call shadows of abstractions. There are regularities in the physical patterns that mathematicians think about. There are facts about circles which they can prove. There are other claims about circles that they cannot prove, or whose negations they can prove. It seems like we might arrange physical objects any way we like; wouldn't that mean that if it's truly all just physics, we could form any pattern and thus "prove" anything we wanted?
The answer lies in the constraints the patterns must follow to be considered valid proofs.
Whether a theorem T is provable can be considered equivalent to a question of whether a physical object, adhering to certain physical constraints, can be constructed. The physical object could be, for example, a book of graph paper with some of the boxes colored in and others left blank, thereby representing a binary code interpretable as a proof. The physical constraints state which subsets of boxes may be colored in, thereby encoding syntactic validity of the proof - as could be checked by a computer or other purely mechanical means.
Mathematics viewed through this lens is an engineering discipline; can we, or can we not, construct an object to a given specification? All that mathematicians say can be viewed as being ultimately about this type of question.
Physical properties such as the constraints on the boxes mentioned above can be fairly abstract, so it is not so surprising that mathematics, also abstract, could reduce to them.

This sort of “mechanical” conception of mathematics doesn’t account for matters like: Why is contemporary mathematics formalized in “standard” first-order logic and not, say, modal logic or intuitionistic logic (which doesn’t assume the law of excluded middle)? Why is ZFC the default foundational axiom system as opposed to NFU or something? These were all decisions sort of collectively made by mathematicians over decades in a way that I don’t think can be reduced to this sort of “mechanical” process. Also, these questions are not 100% “settled”: research in foundations continues to this day.

@NikS Unless you propose the mathematicians were influenced in their decision to adopt ZFC by non-physical causes, then the reason they adopted ZFC is the physics in their brains causing them to do that.

Well, that seems like a reasonable argument. But at that point it seems like you’re dealing with a question that’s in no way specific to mathematics, i.e. whether all human behavior reducible to physics (in other words, is materialist determinism true)


SINCE mathematicians are physical beings...
Mathematics is physics

You affirm the consequent and then 'prove' it.
That may constitute a truth in a trivial way; it does not constitute a proof.
Instead, how about asking and listening to mathematicians themselves?
1. Paul Erdős

Erdős used the verb died when a mathematician stopped doing math; for the case of what we (ordinary mortals) normally call “death” he used the verb “left”
Paraphrased from Obituary

Whether Erdős ‘died’ or merely ‘left’ can be seen from the importance that mathematicians give to the Erdős number
Some others
2. G.H. Hardy

Mathematical reality lies outside us, our function is to discover or observe it, and the theorems which we prove, and which we describe grandiloquently as our 'creations,' are simply the notes of our observations

3. Kronecker

God made the integers, all else is the work of man

Note the »all« — who if not mathematicians come closest to integers?
Whether 1880s German zahlen should rendered as 2024 English integer or natural number is a bit murky to me
4. Cantor

Cantor identified the Absolute Infinite with God, and he considered his work on transfinite numbers to have been directly communicated to him by God, who had chosen Cantor to reveal them to the world
Theology of Cantor

5. Ramanujan

An equation for me has no meaning unless it expresses a thought of God

¿Metaphor?
Now some people may protest:
All these people and their quotes are fine. But they are metaphorical!
To which I can only reiterate:
Assuming the Consequent!
And end with:
6. Pythagoras

All is number

7. Plato

The knowledge at which geometry aims is the knowledge of the eternal


"Zahlen" is simply "numbers", unqualified. When a 4 year old uses the word you can assume natural numbers below 100; when a mathematician uses it, you cannot ;-).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes precisely!

@Peter-ReinstateMonica : I believe Kronecker used the term “ganzen Zahlen”, which literally translates as “whole numbers”. So presumably he’s talking about either the natural numbers or the integers.

@NikS Ah yes, all quotes say "ganze Zahlen" which is integral numbers.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica My point was that today (following Cantor) we believe ℕ ⊆ ℤ ⊆ ℚ ⊆ ℝ. I dont believe that Kronecker would say that is a false claim pre se. I believe he'd say that reifying the distinctions into distinct sets is counterproductive to doing good math. Eg. consider that the fibonnaci sequence, one of the most ℕ-ish sequences one could imagine, mysteriously converges to (powers of) the irrational (1 + √5)/2

@NikS So Kronecker's Zahlen is more vague and informal than Cantor's hierarchy. See the above comment

I think it's potentially misleading, although not necessarily incorrect, to say that it reduces down to "physics". This implies that it reduces down to our theories of physics themselves, which is equally a construct of the mind as mathematics is, and I'm sure you can see how this may become quite circular. You say "physical agents can only derive mathematical conclusions that are allowed by the laws of physics", but similarly, physical agents can only derive theories of physics which are allowed by the laws of physics. This is assuming that such laws exist in the first place. It's an unavoidable, yet incredibly hefty assumption to make, that reality can be described by neat, understandable laws.
In short, your perspective is hinting at what's called a realist school of thought, which is one that I tend to heavily agree with. Realism, in general, is the claim that things simply are the way they are. Mathematicians often abstract themselves and try to claim that math exists as a system of logic independent of reality, but this of course isn't true, as you've pointed out. What is "logic", "math", or even "reality" without some agent to define it and give it meaning? Do these concepts somehow exist and have meaning independent of our ability to assign said meaning? Of course not. By the simple fact that everything in reality must be perceived by an agent in order to have meaning, meaning does not exist independent of agency. I would even take this a step further and claim that the idea of objectivity is rather absurd, although that's certainly a much more contested idea.
To answer your question, I wouldn't say that mathematics reduces down to physics, but I would say that everything (quite literally everything) reduces down to perception and, namely, the very fact that we perceive.

It does not follow.
There's a famous Star Trek quote "Even logic must give way to physics." Elsewhere I have given arguments along the lines of logic must contain all physics, and therefore first order logic is insufficient. So it would seem that you're right; but we can't prove the conclusion from the premise.
You probably heard the quote "God created the integers, the rest is the work of man." When I went to college, we had a different saying: "God created the real numbers, the integers always existed." And the latter seems to be true. We have constructed metaphysics for which the real numbers don't exist; but the integer numbers are inescapable.
I can't prove the result either way nor do I know how the correct answer should be constructed, but the interesting question is "What happens should God try to do math?"

Nothing you have wrote is specific to mathematics; in the sense of you post, any human activity, including art, literature, philosophy, etc., "reduces to physics". Which is correct if you wish, but says nothing interesting.

Physical agents can only derive mathematical conclusions that are allowed by the laws of physics.

Most of mathematics we are doing is very far from limits of what is "allowed by the laws of physics." Indeed, a product of two numbers can be calculated by a human in their head, by a human on a piece of paper, on abacus, on a calculator etc. In each cases, the physical principles underlying the calculation are completely different, but the result is the same. Mathematical reasoning, in general, is built of blocks that are so robust that they are obviously implementable in the physical world, and that in a number of ways (in a brain, on paper, in a proof assistant). This physical implementation is irrelevant for the results.
Of course, there is a sense in which physical reality influences our ability to do mathematics. For example, for a mathematical open problem, such as P ≠ NP, we could in principle try to brute-force search for a proof. Physical limitations suggest that this is likely to take longer than our Universe will exist, so this is out of question in practice. We could also imagine a world where a proof of P ≠ NP exists, but it is so long that physical limitations preclude us from ever storing it (let alone finding). This would be perhaps as close as it get to a "mathematical conclusions that is not allowed by the laws of physics".

"Most of mathematics we are doing is very far from limits of what is "allowed by the laws of physics." - When was the last time a mathematician's brain broke the laws of physics?

If one assumes that all of reality is physical, then any entity must be either physical or not real.  At such a point, making statements about "mathematics" is nothing more than an exercise in substituting in a noun into that phrasing.  In particular, it points towards some quirky statements like stating that imagination reduces to physics.  This is not necessarily an untrue statement, but it does point towards it being rather tricky to draw conclusions from that point.
Personally, a case study I find useful is the construction of the integral in calculus.  We reason about physical things, such as trajectories, using our physical brains, and come to conclusions we consider valid.  But the current accepted root underlying integration is an infinite series of additions which no human brain could ever possibly execute.
Of course, as you point out, we don't actually operate on infinite series.  We operate on mental images describing such an infinite series, which are inherently finite (at least I think we do!).  Do we ascribe the meaning of "integral" to this finite image?  Or the infinite series?
Likewise, if one is cooking, is a "recipe" a piece of paper with printed dots of toner melted onto it, or is it a logical concept of how one puts together a dish?
At some point it gets tricky to operate in only physical terms because the similarity between two physical things (such as a piece of paper which is called a "recipe" and a dish) becomes important, and has to also be captured physically.  Likewise, the arrow of time becomes a very important detail.
And at some point, I think it's valid to say that whether one writes "mathematics resolves to physics" or "mathematics does not resolve to physics" is a small detail amidst the substantial reframing of the universe using a language that is not provably wrong but is indeed different than how the words have been historically used.

That 'chemistry reduces to physics' stems from quantum mechanical models' ability to predict chemistry results to the degree that our processing power allows us to verify. There is no well-understood path from the biochemistry and the [inferred] tensor mapping of our brains to any mathematical theorem, so saying math reduces to physics would be using the phrase in a fundamentally new and different way from how people have used 'reduces to.'
Computerized proof-assistants have confirmed millions of human mathematical results. This point is fairly devastating to the idea that math reduces to physics. It would be merely a single point against if all computers ran on the same hardware and operating systems, but operating systems abstract the processing away to an instruction set which can be run on millions of different types of chips. And proof assistants may be run on hundreds of different operating systems.
Let's examine your conjecture a bit more though. Basically, you're saying that because it requires physical things to make math, math must be physics. If I said that it requires physical things to make a religion (idols, books, meeting places, etc...), would that make religion physics? If I said that democracy requires physical things, does that make democracy physics?
Maybe we examine it from a logical perspective:
if [world NOT physical] then [NOT math]
Your conjecture is vacuously true, but unfortunately, so is:
if [world NOT physical] then [math]

"Computerized proof-assistants have confirmed millions of human mathematical results. This point is fairly devastating to the idea that math reduces to physics." - I fail to see how. Computerized proof-assistants do not violate the laws of physics as far as I'm aware. Whatever results computerized proof-assistants arrive at, those results are physical states in a physical universe. Everything you said is still within the boundaries of physics. Computers rely on transistors, electricity, circuits, etc. All of that is physical

"And proof assistants may be run on hundreds of different operating systems." - So what? That's still within physics.

If I measure something's mass with a spring, then a fulcrum balance, then a piezoelectric crystal, etc... it becomes clear that the mass isn't dependent on the way that I measure it - it's intrinsic to the object. Computers essentially perform a 'measurement' of whether a collection of statements are true given a certain set of axioms. That they all arrive at the same conclusion in millions of different ways indicates that there's an intrinsic truth there - not something dependent on the physics. Your questions indicate you'd be better off focusing on the truth table at the end.

Also, operating systems are distinctly un-physical. You can run one inside of another [inside of another inside of ...]. While you'd be right in saying that for every implementation so far there has been a physical layer, you'd be wrong if you said it was required - all the non-physical computer would need to do is fulfill the instruction set requirements.

Your analogy appeals to different physical processes producing results that are consistent with a physical property: mass. Nothing in your analogy goes beyond physics. The fact that multiple computers arrive at physical states that are interpreted to be the "same conclusion" (notice that this interpretation is made by a physical human brain) indicates that the physical laws of this universe allow the emergence of patterns and consistent results. At no point you have gone beyond physics.

"Also, operating systems are distinctly un-physical." - Really? Where is an example of an un-physical operating system?

Do you have an example of something un-physical as an example? As in an example of an un-physical anything.

You were the one who introduced the concept of un-physical operating systems and claimed that they exist, as well as the concept of non-physical computers, asserting that they, too, exist. I'm not convinced. When was the last time you found an existing non-physical operating system or non-physical computer? Where/how can I find it?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

That's where multidimensional maths becomes relative...
Mathematicians compose equations for N th dimenions beyond 2d, 3d, i.e. 12d which can in some instances contradict physics completely.
Conversely, everything relates to the physical, else it is a void, and information also is physical because it has to be kept on a physical medium.
If we consider fractals, i.e. mandelbrot 2d, 3d, 7d, it's a pretty good example of the physicality of mathematics.
Perhaps 2d and 3d physics is fairly stable for informatin systems, that's why we can't very well imagine universes that are stable with very different dimensions, same as life is only stable in H2O with specific conditions.

You begin by assuming that mind reduces to physics - that we can traverse the (emergent) hierarchy of physics->chemistry->biology->mind by translating all of the phenomena of mind into the language of physics "without remainder". Few believe that even chemistry can be reduced to physics let alone biology or mind.  For example, the chemical property of the wetness of water does not appear to reduce to hydrogen and oxygen atoms, nor does the biological property of "being alive" reduce to the fundamental particles of physics.
While a compete map of the connectome may tell us how a particular mental state is instantiated it will not tell us anything about the meaning that a mental state has to the owner of the brain.  For example, a particular configuration of neurons firing may correspond to seeing red, but it does not tell us what it is like to see red.
I would therefore suggest that your argument is not sound since it is based on a false premise.

The premises reduce to absurdity before you get far enough for it to matter whether mind is physical or not.

If contemplation requires a certain kind of thing, the thing contemplated reduces to a property of that kind of thing.
Contemplation requires mind. (Or a thinking process, if you prefer.)
Mind is physical.


Temporarily omitting 3 we reduce 1 and 2 to absurdity:

1 and 2, therefore all things contemplated are properties of mind.
I contemplate nonexistence.
Therefore nonexistence is a property of mind.
That which exists not contemplates not.
4 and 6 are a contradiction, therefore 1 or 2 is false.


If we want we can add 3 back in and reduce 1,2, 3 to absurdity:

2 and 3 therefore the substrate of contemplation is physical.
1 and 9 therefore all things contemplated are properties of the physical (the contemplation of which is physics).
I am a physical being which contemplates nonexistence.
Therefore nonexistence is a property of the physical.
Therefore I exist not.
That which is not contemplates not.
14 and 11 are a contradiction, therefore 1, 2, and/or 3 is false.



Using bricks does not determine which house to build,
a tool does not determine what to manufacture,
the physical brain does not determine which thoughts to think,
and mathematical invention is not bound by the laws of the present
universe.

Reduction in the wrong direction is an error of category.

"and mathematical invention is not bound by the laws of the present universe" - How so?

@user80226 By mathematical simulation of rather different physical laws.

But how do you do a mathematical simulation?

@user80226 I specify the mathematical laws which control the simulation. Then I implement the specification within my computer: The design runs the machine.

"I specify the mathematical laws which control the simulation. Then I implement the specification within my computer: The design runs the machine" - All of this is constrained by the laws of physics of this universe. You are not actually creating a new universe with different laws. You are still within the boundaries of this universe when you run a simulation under the laws of this universe.

@user80226 It's obvious that we cannot leave the present universe. But the present universe does not restrict the type of my simulation, but implements it.

Analogies alone aren't an argument. I don't really see a connection between these statements besides their form, but a connection of form isn't a connection of meaning, and certainly isn't necessarily one of truth.

@JosephKopp I agree with your general remark. - But for the specific case: Mathematics are thoughts and the brain is a physical system. No theory in neuroscience reduces and explains specific thoughts by the physiology which underlies specific neuronal processes. That's not an analogy. It answers the specific question by deriving the answer from a general case.

No.
That mathematical reasoning relies on physics does not imply that mathematics "reduces to" physics.
You would require the additional premise:

if reasoning about A relies on physics, then A reduces to physics.

You haven't provided that as a premise, nor any reason to think it is true.

"if reasoning about A relies on physics, then A reduces to physics." - How about all mathematics that we will ever know of reduces to physics? Any counterexample you try to come up with will involve a physical agent gaining a mathematical insight using their physical cognitive faculties, so it will always be constrained by the laws of physics.

We can obtain all kinds of amusing conclusions if we generalize to "if reasoning about A relies on X then A reduces to X". Reasoning about vegetable soup relies on human brains. What have I done?! I am a cannibal!

"That mathematical reasoning relies on physics does not imply that mathematics 'reduces to' physics" - what distinction are you drawing between "mathematical reasoning" and "mathematics"? Is there a part of mathematics, different from "reasoning," that you propose does not reduce to physics?

@Lowri "You haven't provided that as a premise, nor any reason to think it is true." - But you haven't proved the negation of the premise either, nor shown any reason to think that it is false in this case, so your answer should have been "I don't know" instead of "No," as claiming "No" shifts the burden of proof onto you (as you need to show that your "No" is true). If you are agnostic about this, simply say "I don't know".

I think not necessarily, because of how heavily math uses symbols.  Symbols stand for things outside themselves, and so it's quite conceivable that symbols reducible to physics may stand for concepts not reducible in the same way.
For example, I am American, and we pledge allegiance to our American flag; but that flag is a symbol for our country.  The country is more than wood and thread and red, white, and blue dye.  Similarly, while mathematical symbols on ink and paper can be reduced to physics, with their corresponding brain states, I think they can symbolize things which cannot be.
Even if humans were entirely physical, I'm not sure that would necessarily mean they would be incapable of using meaningful symbols representing things outside the physical.  And if the physical brain is merely the vehicle of an immaterial mind, as I believe, then the existence of symbols of immaterial concepts would be all but inevitable, I would say.

Many Americans do not pledge allegiance to the American flag.

+1 Even though, once again, I don't think I can agree. But imo this hits a (or perhaps the) core, open question - how to think of the relation between (finite) symbols and  meaning.
